# Solving polynomial congruence by knowing the roots

Tags: discrete-mathematics, polynomials, modular-arithmetic

I was trying to find a simple way to solve a congruence of the type:

$$
(x-\lambda_1)\dotsi(x-\lambda_n) \equiv 0 \mod{m}
$$

So I know the roots of the polynomial and m is some integer. I was wondering whether the roots are the only solutions but apparently it is not since for instance:

$$
(x-148)(x-164) \equiv 0 \mod{m}
$$

has solutions like $29, 38, 94, 148, 164, 218, 274, 283$. How can I find these all? I would like not to use any advanced theorem if it is possible.

Thank you,
Dave

Comment: Surely $x= \lambda_1 , \dots , \lambda_n$ are trivial solutions. The non-trivial ones depend on the specific value of $m$. For example, if $m$ is a prime number, there is no other solution. But if $m$ is composite, there might be some other, or maybe not.

Comment: How can I find these? Do I have to try all the numbers below m for instance?

Comment: You need Hensel's Lifting Theorem to solve this. See for example: https://www.directknowledge.com/polynomial-congruences/

Comment: Oh ok, thank you!

Comment: If $m$ is prime the solutions are $m k + 164\;, m h + 148$ for any $h,k\in\mathbb{Z}$